# Azure APIM is restricting all the IP addresses

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

I created an api in api management instance. I'm trying to test the api in the portal.I observed the below error message.I found this error message once i enable the tracing. May I know how can I allow the IP addressee's. I added the IP filter to allow the IP address. But every time I'm seeing the different IP.
**Caller IP address was not on the allowed list. Access was denied.**

I tried adding the ip address to unblock it by using ipfilter inbound policy

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

- You have allowed only specific IPs in the Ip-filter policy of the API.
- If IP Address is changing every time, observe the IP Addresses Range and add that range to IP-filter policy.
- Also, check in which section you have saved the IP Addresses in IP-filter policy:
  [image]

The Same mentioned in the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-error-handling-policies#predefined-errors-for-policies) of Azure APIM Error handling policies:
[image]